# Problema al filtrar datos en pandas utilizando múltiples condiciones

Tags: python, excel, pandas, filtro

estoy trabajando en una proyecto para filtrar pedidos de tienda en retail mediante Python.
Los archivos que me llegan están en formato Excel y utilizo pandas para acceder a las hojas. Para mi código estoy utilizando una hoja ejemplo para probar. Este es un ejemplo de como se  ve mi hoja en Excel:
[image: Excel: EJEMPLO, hoja: Hoja1]
Mi objetivo a es utilizar un filtro para obtener todos los estilos que tienen unidades en traspasos, es decir, en la columna O.
El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
# Nombre de las columnas que me serviran para filtrar la hoja 
filtros = ["ESTILO", "COLOR"]

# Filtros aplicados a modo de ejemplo. Aqui se crea una dataframe con las columnas a eliminar
sku_entraspasos = hoja1[(hoja1["EN TRASPASOS"] > 0)]
skufiltrados = sku_entraspasos[filtros]
```

El resultado de sku_filtrados es:

```
    ESTILO  COLOR
16  319590  ROME9
17  319594  AZOS3
18  319598  AZME9
23  319606  MOCL1
24  319612  BLANC
25  319614  BLNA1
26  319614  ROME9
27  319615  BLNA1
28  319615  ROME9
```

Mi objetivo es utilizar estos filtros para eliminar las columnas de otra hoja del mismo Excel llamada REPO para dejar solo los estilos que no tengan unidades en traspasos.
Así se ve la hoja REPO:
[image: Excel: EJEMPLO, hoja: REPO]
La parte de mi código que filtra la información, es decir, elimina las filas de la hoja REPO que cumplan con las condiciones de estilo y color de sku_filtrados es la siguiente:

```
# Se crea la columna ESTILO para que sirva de llave con la hoja anterior
REPO["ESTILO"] = REPO["SKU"].astype(str).str.slice(0, 6).astype("Int64")

# Se indican las filas que cumplen condiciones de estar tanto en los filtros como en la hoja REPO
condiciones = (REPO["ESTILO"].isin(sku_entraspasos["ESTILO"])) & (
    REPO["COLOR"].isin(sku_entraspasos["COLOR"]))
# Se filtra el archivo considerando todos los valores que no se encuentren en condiciones
archivo_filtrado = REPO[~condiciones]

# Se guarda el archivo con los SKUs filtrados
columnas_a_guardar = ['ESTILO', 'SKU', 'COLOR',
                      'TIENDA_ORIGEN', 'TIENDA_DESTINO', 'QTY']
archivo_filtrado = archivo_filtrado[columnas_a_guardar]
```

Como resultado, deberia eliminar de la hoja REPO todas las filas que cumplan con un estilo y color determinados, los que se encuentran en sku_filtrados. Sin embargo, pareciera que ***no esta filtrando correctamente.***
En Hoja1 tengo el siguiente estilo con distintos colores:
[image: Excel: EJEMPLO, Hoja: Hoja1]
Como ven, el estilo 319606 de color MOCL1 esta en sku_filtrados, mientras que el mismo estilo de color BLNA1 no, y, de todos modos este ultimo se esta eliminando de mi hoja REPO.

No entiendo ya que a mi parecer, la línea que establece las condiciones:

```
condiciones = (REPO["ESTILO"].isin(sku_entraspasos["ESTILO"])) & (
    REPO["COLOR"].isin(sku_entraspasos["COLOR"]))
```

Establece que las filas que devuelva True deben cumplir ambas condiciones al mismo tiempo.
Este es el codigo completo por si sirve para ayudarme a determinar el error.

```
import pandas as pd


# El programa lee la hoja1 del excel, la cual contiene los criterios de selección de SKUs a enviar
hoja1 = pd.read_excel("EJEMPLO.xlsx", sheet_name="Hoja1")

# Nombre de las columnas que me serviran para filtrar la hoja
filtros = ["ESTILO", "COLOR"]

# Filtros aplicados a modo de ejemplo. Aqui se crea una dataframe con las columnas a eliminar
sku_entraspasos = hoja1[(hoja1["EN TRASPASOS"] > 0)]
skufiltrados = sku_entraspasos[filtros]

print(skufiltrados)

# Ahora el programa lee la hoja que contiene todos los SKUs
REPO = pd.read_excel("EJEMPLO.xlsx", sheet_name="REPO", header=0)

# Se crea la columna ESTILO para que sirva de llave con la hoja anterior
REPO["ESTILO"] = REPO["SKU"].astype(str).str.slice(0, 6).astype("Int64")

# Se indican las filas que cumplen condiciones de estar tanto en los filtros como en la hoja REPO
condiciones = (REPO["ESTILO"].isin(sku_entraspasos["ESTILO"])) & (
    REPO["COLOR"].isin(sku_entraspasos["COLOR"]))
###################################
columnas_a_guardar = ['ESTILO', 'SKU', 'COLOR',
                      'TIENDA_ORIGEN', 'TIENDA_DESTINO', 'QTY']
archivos_eliminados = REPO[condiciones]
archivos_eliminados = archivos_eliminados[columnas_a_guardar]
archivos_eliminados.to_excel("eliminados.xlsx",
                             index=False, sheet_name="NombreDeTuHoja")
###################################
# Se filtra el archivo considerando todos los valores que no se encuentren en condiciones
archivo_filtrado = REPO[~condiciones]

# Se guarda el archivo con los SKUs filtrados
columnas_a_guardar = ['ESTILO', 'SKU', 'COLOR',
                      'TIENDA_ORIGEN', 'TIENDA_DESTINO', 'QTY']
archivo_filtrado = archivo_filtrado[columnas_a_guardar]
archivo_filtrado.to_excel("filtrados.xlsx",
                          index=False, sheet_name="NombreDeTuHoja")

# Se eliminan columnas que no se consideran para el archivo a cargar
columnas_a_eliminar = ['ESTILO', 'COLOR']
archivo_minimos = archivo_filtrado.drop(columns=columnas_a_eliminar)

# Se crea el archivo csv listo para cargar
archivo_minimos.to_csv("SSG01.csv", index=False, header=False)

# print(condiciones.to_string())
```

Agradezco de antemano

Comment: La implementación de tu código me parece correcta, no logro identificar cual puede ser el error, sin embargo, se me ocurre que puedes implementar lo siguiente para eliminar correctamente tus registros:
- Haz la comparación concatenada, es decir, evalúa que la concatenación entre SKU y Color de tu tabla repo está justamente entre la misma concatenación de tus sku_filtrados.